# how to deal with IE fullscreen mode toolbar hiding page content

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

IE has a interesting fullscreen mode. I still don't understand it very well but I have observed two cases:

1. The menu bar and additional attached toolbars hide (slide up) and it is a real real fullscreen experience. This is kind of nice.

   [image: Full full mode]
2. The window frame (chrome) disappears but the menu bar and other bars still remain. They float and hide the page content partiallly.

   I have looked at some pages and they basically don't deal with it. Stackoverflow.com is an example of this. The black top toolbar is hidden and the scrollbar is hidden partially too. I cannot know whether I am logged in or not (or how many reputation I have). **This is problematic** since I have various buttons near the top corner and when in fullscreen mode the user is not able to click on them.

   [image: [fullmode with toolbars]]

Should I try to deal with it? If so how? (I would need to know how many pixels the toolbar takes to move my button accordingly. It varies since people are can attach as many as toolbars as they want)

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: The toolbars only show if the mouse moves to the top of the screen. It is under the user's control whether the toolbar shows or not.

Comment: These bars only show up if the mouse is moved to the very top of page.. so what is the problem?

Comment: May I ask you what exact version do you have? I have the `ie 11.0.9600.17420` and sometimes when the `auto-hide` (toolbar) option is disabled it shows on top of my page (floating). Hence it hides part of my page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have upgraded from version `11.0.9600.17420` to `11.0.9600.18204` and it works consistently now. The page is only hidden when the mouse is near the top :)